# XML Counting TXT

Tags: xml, recursion, tree

Look at the following of XXX data:

```
lala XXX = EL String [XXX]
         | TXT String
         | MMS String
```

For this, the XXX data `<r><r>y</s>pp<s>z</r></r>` is built by

```
lala "r" [ Element "ss" [Text "er"], 
              Text "dd",
              Element "pp" [Text "tet"] ]
```

Comment: This is basically a slightly more elaborate version of exercises basically every source teaching Haskell includes.

Comment: You'll need to write a function that pattern matches on the two different cases of the `XML` type, and recursively calls itself on any sub-nodes that are also of `XML` type...

Answer (score 2):

Since this is essentially homework, I'll give you hints instead of the answer.

What is the answer for a Text item?  Write it down in a form of "elemCount (Text _) = ...."

What is the answer for an "Element" item?  Write it down in a form of "elemCount (List _ children) = ..."

Answer (score 1):

So, the basic idea is to traverse the tree and look for all data constructors matching `XML`. Our function simply returns 1 for any `Text` data constructor and 1 plus the sum of all sublists for a `Element` data constructor. Thus, it looks like this:

```
countTags (Element _ list) = 1 + sum $ map countTags list
countTags _ = 1
```

That's the basic solution. But it is a bit inefficient, since it uses real recursion. A better idea would be to pass a counter and to the list traversal by hand:

```
countTag = countTag' 0 where
  countTag' n (Element _ list) = foldr (flip countTag') (n+1) list
  countTag' n _ = (n+1)
```

I didn't compared these two functions, but by intuition, the second should perform better.

Comment: "Our function simply returns 0 for any Text data constructor" - shouldn't it return 1 for that?